# Real setTimeout type

Tags: typescript

Consider following code:

```html
<script> var x = { setTimeout: setTimeout };                            </script>
<script> x.setTimeout(function () { console.log(1) });     // TypeError </script>
<script> (0,x.setTimeout)(function () { console.log(2) }); // Ok        </script>
```

Call to `setTimeout` with `this` other then `null`, `undefined` and `window` crashes with

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Now I'm writing similar code in typescript and I get a very different results:

```
function f() { }

var x = { setTimeout };
x.setTimeout(f); // Fine for TS
(0, x.setTimeout)(f); // Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.
```

And there are some problems:

1. TS inferred type with strange `this`.
2. `0` has side effects - it changes `this` in function call.
   [Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48254079/4928642) via `0 as any` instead of `0`.
3. I've [tried](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20f%28%29%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x%20%3D%20%7B%20setTimeout%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ax.setTimeout%28f%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Fine%20for%20TS%0D%0A%280%2C%20x.setTimeout%29%28f%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Left%20side%20of%20comma%20operator%20is%20unused%20and%20has%20no%20side%20effects.%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20A%20%3D%20%28this%3A%20void%29%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ST%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20setTimeout%3A%20%28this%3A%20T%2C%20f%3A%20%28%29%20%3D%3E%20void%29%20%3D%3E%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x1%3A%20ST%3Cvoid%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20setTimeout%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ax1.setTimeout%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%280%2C%20x1.setTimeout%29%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x2%3A%20ST%3Cundefined%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20setTimeout%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ax2.setTimeout%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%280%2C%20x2.setTimeout%29%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x3%3A%20ST%3Cundefined%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20Window%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20setTimeout%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ax3.setTimeout%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%280%2C%20x3.setTimeout%29%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x4%3A%20ST%3CWindow%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20setTimeout%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ax4.setTimeout%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%280%2C%20x4.setTimeout%29%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20x5%3A%20ST%3Cnever%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20setTimeout%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ax5.setTimeout%28f%29%3B%0D%0A%280%2C%20x5.setTimeout%29%28f%29%3B) several ways to explicitly declare `this`, but none of them made first call invalid and second valid (or even with only error about side effects) at the same time.

**Is it possible to declare function signature so that it may be executed only with global or void context?**

Comment: Using the comma operator to unbind `this` is probably not idiomatic enough for TypeScript maintainers to support it.  According to [Microsoft/TypeScript#10814](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10814) they are trying to prevent some common mistakes.  If you really want to do this, you can use `void 0` instead of `0`.  By the way, `0` does not have side effects; it's the comma operator that has effects.  The `0` does not make any changes to anything, and its value gets thrown out by the comma operator, so TypeScript warns about it.  I think `void` explicitly turns off that check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redeclare `setTimeout` signature with using `this` argument:

```
declare function setTimeout(this: Window | void, handler: (...args: any[]) => void, timeout: number): number;
declare function setTimeout(this: Window | void, handler: any, timeout?: any, ...args: any[]): number;

var x = { setTimeout: setTimeout };    
x.setTimeout(function () { console.log(1) });  // error: x is not window
setTimeout(function () { console.log(1) }); // ok
```

Comment: Where do you see error? There are no any errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T7rj.png

Comment: The problem is that you don't want to [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) the declaration; you want to completely override it.  You can either do this if you change the definition of `setTimeout` in your lib.d.ts, or if you put your code in a [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) so that `setTimeout` is understood as a local function and not the global one.  (So if you add any `export` statement in your code you will get this to work I think)

Comment: I've checked it on ts 2.7

Comment: The problem with overriding the global `setTimeout` is that ts always choose version in the `lib.d.ts`. I don't know how to say to ts that is your version of function declaration must be higher order.

Comment: For example: 
    declare function A(handler: any): void;
    declare function A(this: {foo: number}, handler: any): void;

    var y = { A };    
    y.A(123); // no error

Comment: I've created issue about that: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21181

Comment: It's not an ordering issue; when you merge function declarations, you are adding an *overload* which does indeed precedence... but if an overload fails to match TypeScript will *go on to the next one*, and the one with no `this` restriction will always match.  As I said, you need to *override* it (meaning, replace the version in lib.d.ts with your own), or *shadow* it (by making TypeScript think there is a *local* function named `setTimeout()`).  Either way.

Comment: Yes, I understand you, exactly this issue I've created

Comment: You are right, `this: Window | void` is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

### Prologue

Typescript is a typed language that transpiles to javascript.

In general Typescript does not use typing to drive javascript generation.

Type information are needed to assure that contracts between callers and callees are satisfied: when type checker has verified that all constraints are satisfied then compiler output does not contain anymore type information but plain javascript.

### Similar code different result?

Said that it is not possible to obtain different result with the same code.

To see that, it could help to set `noEmitOnError` compilerOption to `false` and inspect the generated javascript code: the transpiled code is equivalent to the native javascript.

To answer to your questions:

> TS inferred type with strange this.

TS does infer that `this` is `x`, and this is fine.

> 0 has side effects - it changes this in function call

You are right, but it seems considered not idiomatic to use this construct, see @jcalz comment and also [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12978)

> I've tried several ways to explicitly declare this, but none of them made first call invalid and second valid (or even with only error about side effects) at the same time

For the reason said in prologue above, typing it is not the tool for resolving your problem, as you can see all your trials generate the same output.

> Is it possible to declare function signature so that it may be executed only with global or void context? And how can I call it in that way without using call, apply and temporery variables?

Not sure to understand this question. I would say that you may declare anything in typescript. If you lie the compiler will produce no error but the runtime will fail.

Comment: _"TS does infer that this is x, and this is fine"_ - yes, but by some reason it doesn't check that this type doesn't fit the function.

_"If you try in node environment"_ - node environment allows to call `setTimeout` with any `this`. But in general it has same side effect and it can easily be checked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xjoz.png

_"typing it is not the tool for resolving your problem"_ - actually it is that tool as a problem is with typing. `x` doesn't have the correct type to mach function signature, but it isn't checked.
And there is nothing about compiled code in my question.

Comment: You are right about node! (0, x.f)() is always different from f(x). (0, x.f) return the last element of the tuple and when this element is a function return the function with an undefined this, so it has side effect.