# Comma operator to reset this

Tags: typescript

In following [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20x%20%3D%20%7B%20f%3A%20function%20()%20%7B%20return%20this%20%3D%3D%3D%20window%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A(0%2C%20x.f)()%3B)

```
var x = { f: function () { return this === window } };
(0, x.f)();
```

I'm using construction `(0, x.f)` to run function with `this` equal to Window (or undefined in strict mode).

But typescript says

> Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.

But actually there is a side effect on `this` of function I'm calling.

How should I write my code to eliminate this error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zero itself really doesn't have side effects, but comma operator does.

So the [possible solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20x%20%3D%20%7B%20f%3A%20function%20()%20%7B%20return%20this%20%3D%3D%3D%20window%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A(0%20as%20any%2C%20x.f)()%3B) is to add `as any` to `0`:

```
var x = { f: function () { return this === window } };
(0 as any, x.f)();
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. Curious to know it there is an explanation (it works also null as null, 0 as number, "a" as string ....)